# Dimension of the Invariant Subspace $((\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 2n})^{\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})}$

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

This was posed as a challenging exercise by my professor. The exercise is to compute the dimension of the invariant subspace of $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 2n}$ viewed as an $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ representation.

For some background, $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ can be viewed as traceless $2 \times 2$ matrices with complex entries. So one common basis we see is

$e = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, f = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, h = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

The standard representation of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ is just by matrix multiplication. Let $v_1 = (1,0)$ and $v_0=(0,1)$. Observe that $ev_1 = fv_0 = 0$, $ev_0 = v_1,fv_1 = v_0$, and $hv_1 = v_1,hv_0 = -v_0$.

In general, if we have a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ acting on two representations $V,W$, then we can define a representation on their tensor product by a Leibniz rule: $a(v \otimes w) = (av) \otimes w + v \otimes (aw)$.

An invariant subspace of a representation $V$ is really all vectors that are annihilated by every element of $\mathfrak{g}$: $V^\mathfrak{g} := \{v \in V: av = 0, \forall a \in \mathfrak{g}\}$.

---

Okay, with that set up, some knowledge of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ tells us that the Lie algebra is completely reducible and all the irreducible complex representations are of the form $V(n) = \langle v_n, v_{n-2}, v_{n-4},...,v_{2-n},v_{-n} \rangle$, a $n+1$ dimensional vector space. The subscripts here represent the **weight** which really means that they are eigenvectors of $h$ with their eigenvalue being the subscript. So $h v_{n-6} = (n-6) v_{n-6}$. I didn't write it this way above but it's mostly due to bookkeeping.

Moreover, $e$ adds $2$ to the weight of vectors while $f$ subtracts $2$ from their weight. $h$ doesn't shift the weight. Anyways, the relevance of this is that the invariant subspace must lie within the weight $0$ subspace because otherwise, $h$ cannot annihilate. Also, under tensor products, weights add.

For example, $\mathbb{C}^2 \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$ has basis: $v_1 \otimes v_1, v_1 \otimes v_0, v_0 \otimes v_1, v_0 \otimes v_0$. The first one has weight $2$, the middle two have weight $0$, the last one has weight $-2$. We can show that $e(v_1 \otimes v_0 - v_0 \otimes v_1) = 0$ and $f$ and $h$ also annihilate this vector. Well, $h$ acts by multiplication by $0$ on the weight $0$ subspace so we don't really need to check $h$.

Note also that if we take $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes n}$ where $n$ is odd, then there are no weight $0$ vectors other than the zero vector. In this case, there cannot be any nontrivial invariant subspace. That's why we take even number of copies.

Now the bookkeeping: I chose $v_1,v_0$ to denote the basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}^2$ because then we can denote the basis elements of $W_{2n} := (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 2n}$ by strings of zeros and ones. So $\dim W_{2n} = 2^{2n}$. Among these, the weight $0$ strings are precisely those with half being zeros, the other half being ones. So the weight zero subspace has dimension ${2n \choose n}$. The invariant subspace has to have dimension smaller than this. I could have chosen $+,-$ instead but it might get confusing to read things like $(+-)-(-+)$.

Also, as an example, in $W_6$, $e(101001) = (111001) + (101101) + (101011)$. Basically, $e$ flips $0$ to $1$ like in computers and but kills $1$; that's why we see only three terms instead of six which we expect from Leibniz's rule. $f$ does the opposite. I suspect that we really only need to study $e$ but I'm not sure.

---

Anyways, with that lengthy prologue (if you read till here, thank you), I admit that I don't see any combinatorial patterns. I thought I had found something when $n=2$ but it fell apart in $n=3$. For $n=2$, I think the invariant subspace has dimension $2$ and is spanned by $(1100)-(1010)-(0101)+(0011)$ and $(1001)-(1010)-(0101)+(0110)$.

Comment: Have you covered the (algebraic) Clebsch-Gordan formula explaining how the tensor product of  two irreducible reps (of known highest weights) of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\Bbb{C})$ splits into a sum of irreducible reps?

Comment: Recursively using Clebsch-Gordan gives $1,2,5,14,42,\ldots$ So your answer for $n=2$ looks right to me.

Comment: You don't need the full $V(n) \otimes V(m)$ splitting into irreps. Just do $V(n) \otimes \mathbb{C}^2$. From there you can get the breakdown of $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes 2n}$ from that for $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes (2n-1)}$ and so on. See a pattern of walking up and down along natural numbers, a counting paths problem.

Comment: Anyway, [this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C14%2C42&sort=&language=english&go=Search) looks like a match. Yeah, as @AHusain explained, you only need $V(0)\otimes V(1)=V(1)$ and $V(m)\otimes V(1)=V(m+1)\oplus V(m-1)$, $m>0$.

Comment: This problem is the 22nd entry on that OEIS page. Again, as @AHusain explained, it is equivalent to a path counting problem (the 3rd entry on that list).

Comment: See also [this thread on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/155589/11619).

Comment: Jyrki's approach is probably the simplest and makes it clear that counting occurrences of $V(0)$ inside $V(1)^{\otimes 2n}$ amounts to counting Dyck paths and so results in Catalan numbers. For a more explicit description of a basis of invariants, due to Kempe in the 19th century, see section 3.7 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505096

Comment: Thank you everyone. This exercise is far more interesting than I first thought.

@AHusain (or Jyrki) Could you explain how this relates to counting paths? In my setup above, a 2n-tuple of 1's and 0's (half of each) can be viewed as telling you how to monotonically traverse an n x n grid (say, 1 means up, 0 means right). But on the Wiki page for Catalan numbers, they restrict their attention to only those that do not cross the diagonal and I don't quite see how that translates over to this situation.

Comment: Turn the picture by 45 degrees and then it becomes up or down paths that do not go under sea level. The split $m+1$, $m-1$ mentioned by Jyrki corrosponds to choosing between an up versus down step. Staying above sea level is because you don't have representations $V(m)$ with $m$ negative. Finally returning to zero altitude at the end is because you want the multiplicity of $V(0)$.

Comment: Finally, try some examples!!!! Use Jyrki's formula for $V(m)\otimes V(1)$ to compute the decomposition of $V(1)^{\otimes 2n}$ for $n=1,2,3,4$ preferably without simplifying, i.e., keep $x+x+x$ as it is instead of writing $3x$. Keep track of the history of the production of a term $x$ and match it with a Dyck path.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Oh, that's very elegant! Thank you.

Comment: You can also do your question using characters if you know what they are. It's about expanding $(q+q^{-1})^{2n}$ in the basis $(q^{m+1}-q^{-m-1})/(q-q^{-1})$, $m=0,1,\ldots$ and figuring out the coordinate for $m=0$.