Given a representation of a group, how does one determine the multiplicity of the irreps?
Let G be a semi-simple Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ be a representation of $G$. $V$ is decomposed by $G$'s irreps as
$$
V = \oplus_{\mu,\lambda} V_{\mu,\lambda},
$$
where $\mu$ labels different irreps and $\lambda$ is a multiplicity label for repeated irreps.
Question: How do you determine the multiplicity of each irrep? Also, is the decomposition of V unique?
A simple example where $G = U(1)$ and $V = (\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes k}$ where perhaps $k$ equals 2 or 3 would be great. Or at least help with the set up for such an example.
My background: I'm up to Ch. 6 [The rep. of $\mathfrak{sl}(3, \mathbb{C}$)] in Hall's Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations and am starting to learn about roots and weights.
In addition to an answer, I'd also appreciate some pointers  towards useful references or key terms to look up.

My copy of Hall's book is apparently packed in a box for the duration of renovations at the math department, so I cannot check the notation. Anyway, the main thing is that once you learn about roots and weights (and formal characters), this kind of questions become somewhat straight forward (when you know the formal characters of the irreducibles).

Anyway, it's not clear how $U(1)$ acts on $\Bbb{C}^2$. If, instead, we use $G=SU(2)$ and specify $V$ to be the natural representation, then $V=V(1)$ (or $V(\lambda_1)$ depending). It is not hard to show that in this case $V^{\otimes2}\simeq V(2)\oplus V(0)$, and $V^{\otimes 3}\simeq V(3)\oplus V(1) \oplus V(1)$. So $V(1)$ appears with multiplicity two. Have you covered Clebsch-Gordan decomposition from $SL_2$-theory (or $SU(2)$)? Many students first meet C-G decomposition on a course in quantum mechanics when studying addition of angular momenta.

The uniqueness is standard and will be covered in any textbook on representation theory. You have to be more specific on the meaning of "how do you determine": Are you asking for theoretical algorithms or existing software or general theory...?

Firstly $U(1)$ is not a semisimple Lie group so isn't your best bet for a basic example. As Jyrki points out $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ (or $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, etc.) is a more natural place to start and the decomposition of $(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\otimes k}$ into isotypic components (i.e. your $V_{\mu,\lambda}$) is called the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition and you can find examples of this easily. Fulton and Harris compute a fair number of examples of these as well in their book Representation Theory.
More generally the decomposition of $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes k}$ as a $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$-representation can be found practically using Schur-Weyl duality. This states that the action of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ commutes with the action of the symmetric group $S_k$ permuting the order of tensors. This means that each isotypic component is precisely the tensor product of an irreducible representation of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and one of $S_k$.
For example, as a $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ representation we have $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes 2} = S^2\mathbb{C}^n \oplus \bigwedge^n\mathbb{C}^n$ where the first corresponds to the part where $S_2$ acts trivially and the second where $S_2$ acts as the "sign representation".
Similarly $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes 3} = S^3\mathbb{C}^n \oplus (V \otimes W) \oplus\bigwedge^3\mathbb{C}^n$ where $V$ is the 2-dimensional "standard" representation of $S_3$ and $W$ is the representation with highest weight $\omega_1 + \omega_2$. Since $V$ is 2-dimensional that means $W$ has multiplicity $2$ in $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes 3}$. Each irrep of $S_k$ will correspond to only one irrep of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ so you have a list of the only possible multiplicities although not every irrep of $S_k$ will appear (we can categorise which ones arise in terms of partitions of $k$).
Applying this by hand to the general case will be hard. I briefly mentioned partitions and there is not even a closed form of the formula for the number of partitions in general. But for low enough $k$ and $n$ we can do this without too much hassle.
For a completely general representation, it really depends on what information you have about the representations. For example if you happen to know how all the Casimir elements act you can determine the irreps straightforwardly. If instead you knew all the weights of your rep you could start with the highest weight spaces and remove copies of the matching irrep until that weight disappears and repeat until done.

The general form for tensor powers of the standard 2-dimensional irrep of $SL(2)$ is given in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155589/schur-weyl-duality-for-sl-2-and-s-n/302206#302206. There might be similar results for higher degrees, but none that I have seen.
